# Iiyama G-MASTER GE2288HS-B1 - Monitors have different colors

Tags: display, colors

I would like to ask. Why I have different colors on two identical iiyama G-MASTER GE2288HS-B1 monitors. Can I calibrate the monitors? It's not the cable and graphics card, because when I swap the cables it's still the same. I have the same monitor settings. Thank you in advance for your reply.

[image]

Comment: I'm taking a guess here, one display is using HDMi, the other is display/dvi?

Comment: I have 3 identical monitors, the 2 I have Display Port connections to are the same colour, the 3rd using HDMI displays as slightly different shades.

Comment: One is connected HDMI -> HDMI. Second is connected DVI -> HDMI. This is not because when I swap the cables, the monitors are still the same as in the photo.

Comment: Most likely a different batch of panels. Unless you calibrate the monitor to a CMYK/ICC profile, you're going to get this.

Comment: How can I calibrate with an ICC profile? I have an ICC profile directly from the manufacturer.

Comment: Are both monitors brand new and from the same source? If one is older than the other it could be backlight ageing, or different batches, or even different panels.

Comment: It looks like the color temperature of both monitors is different. The left one looks much more blue/cold than the right one. Check the color temperature of each monitor using its on screen display and adjust if needed.